# From a LightBDD Decorator, how to retrieve the scenario's current ChromeDriver from the DependencyResolver?

Tags: c#

I'm using [LightBDD](https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD) to run Selenium tests and I'm trying to automatically take a screenshot whenever a scenario fails. I wrote a [class-level LightBDD Decorator](https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD/wiki/Extending-Test-Behavior#class-level) to do this but I retrieve a *new* instance of the ChromeDriver from the `ResourcePool` instead of retrieving the current ChromeDriver.

How can retrieve the scenario's *current* ChromeDriver instead of a new instance?

**More Details**

I'm registering the ChromeDriver as in the [provided example](https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD/wiki/DI-Containers#resourcepool-example-usage), i.e.:

```cs
private void ConfigureContainer(ContainerConfigurator config)
{
    config.RegisterInstance(
        new ResourcePool<ChromeDriver>(CreateDriver),
        new RegistrationOptions());
}

private ChromeDriver CreateDriver()
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    return driver;
}
```

My Decorator:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TakeScreenshotOnErrorAttribute : Attribute, IScenarioDecoratorAttribute
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(IScenario scenario, Func<Task> scenarioInvocation)
    {
        try {
            await scenarioInvocation();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            await TakeScreenshot(scenario);
        }
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    private static async Task TakeScreenshot(IScenario scenario)
    {
        try {
            var driverHandle = scenario.DependencyResolver.Resolve(typeof(ResourceHandle<ChromeDriver>));
            var driver = await ((ResourceHandle<ChromeDriver>) driverHandle).ObtainAsync();
            var screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"c:\temp\error.png");
        }
        catch {
            /* Ignore */
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger clearly shows that a second instance is created:
[image: scenario.DependencyResolver debugger]

Version: LightBDD 3.0.1 with NUnit3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default behavior of LightBDD DI container](https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD/wiki/DI-Containers#default-di-container) is to provide a new instance of the requested dependency every time `Resolve()` method is called.

To make it working as expected a more advanced DI has to be used (like [LightBDD.Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LightBDD.Autofac/) package) and `ResourceHandle<ChromeDriver>` has to be registered with a scope lifetime:

```cs
public class ConfiguredLightBddScopeAttribute : LightBddScopeAttribute
{
    protected override void OnConfigure(LightBddConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.DependencyContainerConfiguration()
            .UseAutofac(ConfigureContainer());
    }

    private ContainerBuilder ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterInstance(new ResourcePool<ChromeDriver>(CreateDriver));
        builder.RegisterType<ResourceHandle<ChromeDriver>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 
        // ^-- this makes the difference
        return builder;
    }

    private ChromeDriver CreateDriver()
    {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

It would mean that while each scenario will get own copy of the handle, the scenario code and the decorator code will get the same instance.

I have provided the working example in a response on the LightBDD issues page: https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD/issues/186